# Перенос проета с Nuxt.js на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет - такой вопрос:
Проект на Nuxt.js возможно переконвертировать таким образом, что бы с ним мог работать человек знающий только vue.js? 
(что бы структура проекта после этого преобразования выглядела как проект на vue.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt.js сам по себе является приложением написанным на vue.js. Nuxt.js всего лишь сохраняет время разработчика , которое он тратит на конфигурацию конфигов, зависимостей , инициализацию плагинов, модулей , настройку SSR и так далее.
А структуры проекта в vue.js как таковой нет, думаю вы имели ввиду vue-cli, но вряд ли есть конвектор из Nuxt.js в Vue.js так как первый является вторым на стеройдах.